# Golang, функции

Tags: функции, golang

В общем не проблема, но нужно для понимания Golang. Можете подсказать что представляет собой строка кода написанная после фигурных скобок функции?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "time"
    "github.com/zhashkevych/scheduler"
)

func main() {

    s := scheduler.NewScheduler()

    s.Add(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context){
        fmt.Printf("Текущее время: %s\n", time.Now())
    }, time.Second * 1)
    
    time.Sleep(time.Minute)

    //fmt.Println("Знакомство с модулями")
}
```

Comment: Там две пары фигурных скобок, какая именно строка интересует?

Comment: Это [closure](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это интервал, который выводит результат каждую секунду. 
У тебя метод `Add` принимает три аргумента. 
`time.Second * 1` - это третий аргумент метода.